# getting php value from option selected

Tags: php, html

I am displaying list of data from database on an option selected tag on html. How to get the value which data is selected on php? The code is as follow

```
<select name="nama" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">


      <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['no'] . "'>'" . $row['nama_tps'] . "'</option>";
             }
        ?> 

 </select>
```

where `$result` is

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT nama_tps FROM tps ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 0,6");
```

Using selected `nama_tps` or `no` there is another data to be inserted, problem is I can't pass it as a parameter because it is out of scope.

The parameter is as follow

```
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// Check input errors before inserting in database
if (empty($berat)) {

    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "UPDATE tps SET berat = ? WHERE no = ?";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_berat, $param_nama);
        // Set parameters
        $param_berat = trim($_POST["berat"]);
        $param_nama = trim($_POST["nama"]);
```

How do you solve this problem? Thank you for your answer

Comment: You should be getting the value on $_POST['"nama"]. On the receiving script, are you ever getting past empty($berat)? I'm asking because it's strange that after passing only if it's empty, you're trying to parse it. Didn't you mean !empty($berat)? Could you clarify what berat is supossed to hold.

Comment: You have to select no as well as nama_tps from the database. Your query selects only nama_tps.  So the option values will be blank. The query should be - SELECT nama_tps, no FROM tps ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 0,6.

Comment: @JuanV i got past it and succesfully queried `$stmt` , berat is supposed to hold number value for the database. What you said make sense, I will try !empty and see if it's different